# When do I split up classes into different scripts?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a project in Unity, and was trying to figure out how to abbreviate a large number into a more readable format. I found somebody who asked the same question and got some code, but the person who gave that code had 2 classes in the same C# script. I am new to Unity and C# in general, so this was not something I had seen before.

What I would like to know is when to put classes in different scripts, when to put multiple classes in the same script, and if I do put multiple classes in the same script how that affects that script and other scripts in the project.

Answer (score 1):

From a C# logical point of view, it does not matter where a class is. From the practical perspective, it is usual to put every type (class, struct) in its own code file. I often make an exception for enums and put enums belonging to the same realm into the same file, e.g. things like `DisplayStyle`, `SortOrder`, `Visibilty` could be in a file named `AppearanceEnums.cs`. Enums are mostly small and don't contain logic.

for Unity, see: [How to architect code as your project scales](https://unity3d.com/how-to/architect-code-as-your-project-scales)

Comment: Good answer! And on a related note, once you find that the class is getting quite large, it can often be [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) for the need to break it up into multiple classes, each of which carries its own responsibility better. This will help maintenance and adding features in the future.